# building highcarts options in views.py

Tags: python, django, highcharts

**AVOID EVAL**

My question has been answered and I ended up using eval, but after some searching on what eval does and can do I ended up not using it and instead used an alternative found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!

---

In my application i'm building the whole chart options in the backend and returning it as a json response

```
def get_chart_data(request):
    chart = {
        'title': {
            'text': ''
        },
        'xAxis': {
            'categories': [],
            'title': {
                'text': ''
            },
            'type': 'category',
            'crosshair': True
        },
        'yAxis': [{
            'allowDecimals': False,
            'min': 0,
            'title': {
                'text': ''
            }
        }, {
            'allowDecimals': False,
            'min': 0,
            'title': {
                'text': ''
            },
            'opposite': True
        }],
        'series': [{
            'type': 'column',
            'yAxis': 1,
            'name': '',
            'data': []
        }, {
            'type': 'line',
            'name': '',
            'data': []
        }, {
            'type': 'line',
            'name': '',
            'data': []
        }]
    }
    return JsonResponse(chart)
```

And then get the data using ajax and use the response for the data

`Highcharts.chart('dashboard1', data);`

I'm ok with this so far but i've run into problems if I want to use highcharts functions as part of the options, for example setting the color of text using `Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]`,

```
'title': {
        'text': 'Rainfall',
        'style': {
            'color': Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
    },
```

If i don't put quotes to this when building the options in `views.py` it would be treated as python code and result in an error, however if i add quotes to it, it will be treated as string in javascript which would not work.

Is this possible? or should i just build the options in javascript and just get the data part in the backend and not the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return the JS code in Django as a string, and then you can run [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) on it, but executing code like that opens the possibility of an XSS attack, especially if the information is user-submittable.

Your best bet otherwise would be to create the styling on the JS end if possible, and manipulate the incoming data.

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var complexJson = {"parent": {"child": "alert('Here is a nested alert!')"}}
  var alertString = "alert('Here is a simple alert!')";
  
  eval(complexJson["parent"]["child"])
  eval(alertString)
})
```

```html
<a href="#">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: How would i add `eval()` to that specific line/value in the json? How do i turn this,`'color': 'Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]'` to this? `'color': eval('Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]')`

Comment: You could easily access the child using something like this: `data["style"]["color"]` - I also updated my answer to show you an example

Comment: Thank you, I changed the value of the key using `data['title']['style']['color'] = eval(data['title']['style']['color'])`, i'll make sure not to evaluate anything related to a user input.